# WPF semi transparent button to control MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mediaelement

I am making WPF application that plays a video.
I use `MediaElement`, I wish to add `Play`/`Pause` button, I want that image button to be in shape of play, and only the image i put on the button will be shown. the rest to be transparent.

e.g: put a play triangle image on a rectangle button will only show the triangle image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to "make your own", fortunately it's not that hard, here is a working example (doesn't handle mouse hovering though):

```
   <Grid Background="Black">
      <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <StackPanel>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
               </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Button.Template>
         <Path Data="M 0,0 L 15,10 L 0,20" Fill="Green"/>
      </Button>
   </Grid>
```

The grid is only here to show that only the arrow is actually drawn, and the Path thing is vectorial data to draw a Play button.

It looks like this:

[image: Play button]

Comment: How can i set image path instead of the Path Data ?

Comment: @ilansch Replace the `<Path ... />` with an `<Image Source="Path_to_image" />`